# ¿Como repetir una función lambda para diferentes valores de una lista?

Tags: python, bucles, float, scipy

la idea es usar el método de newton rhapson que esta en el modulo scipy, la función fx y dfx deben tomar en cuenta cada una de las constantes que estan dentro de las listas, pero no logro hacer que el fx y dux tomen cada uno de los valores por a parte y me de soluciones para cada valor de las listas, este es el código que tengo

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
import numpy as np

F = [27, 11, 5, 7, 11, 13]

X = [7, 11, 5, 7, 11, 13]


X = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]

A = [7, 11 5, 7, 7, 11]

H = list(map(lambda x: 10**((3164/x)-10.4146), F) )


fx  = lambda x: (A + x + H*(x**2))
dfx = lambda x: 1 + 2*(H)*(x)

x0 = 2
tolera = 0.001

opt.newton(fx,x0, fprime=dfx, tol = tolera)
```

cuando lo ejecuto me lanza el siguiente error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ovni321/Documents/nuevo cofio.py", line 38, in <module>
    opt.newton(fx,x0, fprime=dfx, tol = tolera)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/zeros.py", line 280, in newton
    fval = func(p0, *args)
  File "/Users/ovni321/Documents/nuevo cofio.py", line 32, in <lambda>
    fx  = lambda x: A + x + H*(x**2)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list
```

la idea es que tome el primer valor de A y el primer de valor de H y arroje un valor de X (que es para lo que se usa el método de newton rhapson) y así para cada uno, sin embargo no entiendo como realizarlo o que estoy ejecutando mal

Comment: Por que sobrescribe la variable `X`?

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee o visita de nuevo  [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que debes anteponer un título que describa bien el problema que tienes, así como resumir tu pregunta en los primeros párrafos, intentar pegar el código que haga replicar el problema o donde creas que esté el problema, etc. El formular una buena pregunta, aumentará tus posibilidades de recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad.

Comment: esto debe funcionar en todas las ocasiones??

Comment: si sabes que con esta edición mi respuesta queda mal? (por lo valores que utilizo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira tu problema se soluciona con un simple ciclo `for`, esto nos ayudará a coger cada valor de cada lista (en este caso solo `A` y `H`), como necesitamos coger datos de varias listas un `for i in list` no nos servirá, obtaremos por un `for i in range(len(list))` esto solo funciona si todas las listas tienen el mismo tamaño, asi que ten cuidado con eso.

El problema es que tu función `fx` y `dx` solo admiten un parámetro por lo que no podemos pasarle una variable `H` o `A` por tal razón vamos a declarar unas variables como globales y vamos a usar esas en las funciones `fx` y `dx`, el valor se ira cambiando en cada iteración, luego solo realizamos la operación.

```py
#tus listas
F = [325.003171, 335.5223862,334.9285163, 334.3839569,
     334.0441433, 333.6646669, 332.8992823, 332.2796852
    ,331.7501333, 331.2966912,330.6620866 ,330.1293188
    ,329.0026812 ,328.1976338, 327.6273472 ,327.0399092
    ,326.5317967,326.3677857 ,325.7942832 ,335.722844]

X = [1,0.0187,0.0741,0.1249,0.1566,
      0.192, 0.2634, 0.3212, 0.3706,
      0.4129, 0.4721, 0.5218,0.6269,
      0.702, 0.7552, 0.81, 0.8574,
      0.8727, 0.9262, 0]


X = [0, 0.9813, 0.9259, 0.8751, 0.8434, 0.808, 0.7366,0.6788,
      0.6294, 0.5871, 0.5279, 0.4782, 0.3731, 0.298, 0.2448,
      0.19, 0.1426, 0.1273, 0.0738, 1]

A = [2.52538566,0.982892522,1.035325379,1.086003829,
         1.118949869, 1.15699237, 1.237938563,1.307841687,
         1.370889452, 1.427426397,1.510719649, 1.584608188,
         1.753714996, 1.886162904, 1.986352943, 2.095451176,
         2.194920737, 2.228082422, 2.348260036, 0.965833211]

H = list(map(lambda x: 10**((3164/x)-10.4146), F) )

#declaramos variables globales
global a
global h

#declaramos las funciones
fx  = lambda x: (a + x + h *(x**2)) #operamos con las variables globales
dfx = lambda x: 1 + 2*(h)*(x)

x0 = 2 #ponemos el valor de inicio
tolera = 0.001 #ponemos la tolerancia

#hacemos el for
for i in range(len(A)):
    a = A[i] #asignamos el dato a la variable a
    h = H[i] #asignamos el dato a la variable b
   #utilizamos un try/except en caso de errores
    try:
        res = opt.newton(fx,x0, fprime=dfx, tol=tolera)
        print(res) #mostramos el resultado
    except:
        print(f"failed in iteration: {i}") #imprimimos en que iteracion se produjo el error
        pass #no hace nada
```

Coloqué un `try/except` por que me di cuenta que no siempre funciona.

**resultado**

```
failed in iteration: 0
-1.1107414611548596
-1.1870846122102994
-1.2643770483453485
-1.316738363104368
-1.3795550824416118
-1.5232493122791675
-1.6613804191801471
-1.8012763593730183
-1.944031115039576
-2.2022624757960387
-2.531314059031493
failed in iteration: 12
failed in iteration: 13
failed in iteration: 14
failed in iteration: 15
failed in iteration: 16
failed in iteration: 17
failed in iteration: 18
-1.0866115956459224
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, has solucionado por completo mi duda